# JPEG Not recognised by Identify, Paperclip, ImageMagick on Rails 3.1.3 OSX Mountain Lion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, paperclip, osx-mountain-lion, homebrew

I have trawled through all the SO Issues on this but with no joy.

I get the following error since upgrading to Mountain Lion:

```
Validation failed: Photo /var/folders/92/qp3ppxv92tsglvj03ndp0t6m0000gn/T/stream20121007-36927-1dzwbgk-0.jpeg is not recognized by the 'identify' command.
```

and in the log

```
Command :: identify -format %wx%h :file
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #    <Paperclip::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError: /var/folders/92/qp3ppxv92tsglvj03ndp0t6m0000gn/T/stream20121007-36927-1dzwbgk-0.jpeg is not recognized by the 'identify' command.>
```

I am using: Ruby 1.8.7, Rails 3.1.3, OSX Mountain Lion, Homebrew to install dependencies

I have added

```
#development.rb
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin"
```

I have completely removed and reinstalled homebrew

```
#brew doctor
Your system is raring to brew.

#brew list

ack     gettext     imagemagick libffi      libpng      little-cms  pkg-config  readline
cmake       git     jasper      liblqr      libtiff     mysql       postgresql  xz
freetype    glib        jpeg        libmagic    libyaml     ossp-uuid   qt
```

I installed liblqr at the recommendation of another SO case and that brought a lot of dependencies with it.

Identify seems to work from the command line

```
#identify /var/folders/92/qp3ppxv92tsglvj03ndp0t6m0000gn/T/stream20121007-36927-1dzwbgk-0.jpeg
/var/folders/92/qp3ppxv92tsglvj03ndp0t6m0000gn/T/stream20121007-36927-1dzwbgk-0.jpeg JPEG 259x195 259x195+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 11KB 0.000u 0:00.000

#identify -format %wx%h  /var/folders/92/qp3ppxv92tsglvj03ndp0t6m0000gn/T/stream20121007-36927-1dzwbgk-0.jpeg
259x195
```

Identify seems to work from console

`Loading development environment (Rails 3.1.3)
1.8.7 :001 > system("identify -format %wx%h  /var/folders/92/qp3ppxv92tsglvj03ndp0t6m0000gn/T/stream20121007-36927-1dzwbgk-0.jpeg")
259x195
 => true`

I have installed rmagick - though i never used it before. Gems:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS *** 
paperclip (2.7.1)
rmagick (2.13.1)
```

I have tried everything suggested and am now completely out of ideas. Any suggestions for how to dig a little deeper to isolate the problem? The cause is resizing jpeg or PNG files (i haven't tried any others) caused by Paperclip thus:

`has_attached_file :photo,
    :styles => {:thumb => "100x100", :medium  => "x140", :mediumplus => "x210",:large => "960x378" },
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_credentials => {
      :access_key_id => ENV['S3_KEY'],
      :secret_access_key => ENV['S3_SECRET']
    },
    :s3_protocol => "https",
    :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET'],
    :path => ":attachment/:id/:style.:extension"`

Answer (score 3):

Use paperclip 2.8.0 instead of 2.7.1.